Visualizing the Pólya-conjecture (Liouville function)
It might be a better idea to post this on cs, but it is math-related...
So the, or rather one Pólya-conjecture is that for all $n > 0$ integers
$$ L(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \lambda(k) \leq 0 $$
where $\lambda(k) = (-1)^{\Omega(k)}$ and $\Omega(k)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $k$ with multiplicity. For instace, $12 = 2^2 3^1$, so $\Omega(12) = 2 + 1 = 3$.
The conjecture is false, it fails at around 900 million. I want to visualize this by plotting the first 1 billion $(n, L(n))$ points in MatLab, where points appear consecutively (code below). I can sort of do this for the first 1 million points (though towards the end, the plotting slow down quite a bit).
n = 1000002;
step = 2000;
x = linspace(1, n, n);
y = zeros(1, n); 

y(1) = 1;
for k = 2:n
    y(k) = y(k-1) + (-1)^length(factor(k));
end

figure;
h = scatter(x(1),y(1),'.');
xlim([0, n + 1]);
ylim([min(y) - 1, max(y) + 1 + abs(max(y) - min(y))/5]); %/5 is free to choose
yline(0)

for k = 2:step:n
    h.XData = x(1:k); 
    h.YData = y(1:k);
    pause(0.01);
end

Going to 1 billion seems unrealistic in every way: it is rather slow calculation- and plotting-wise, also memory...
Another option is to calculate all the points in python (my code is faster at calculating than MatLab) and save them to a txt file, load that into MatLab as an array (I haven't figured that out yet) and plot it (the plotting would probably slow down towards the end again, almost freeze). Here's the python code:
import numpy as np
import time

def compute_omega(limit):
    omega = np.zeros(limit + 1, dtype=int)
    
    for p in range(2, limit + 1):
        if omega[p] == 0:  # p is a prime
            for multiple in range(p, limit + 1, p):
                power = multiple
                while power % p == 0:
                    omega[multiple] += 1
                    power //= p
    
    return omega

def main():
    n = 10000000
    
    omega_values = compute_omega(n)
    
    liouville = np.ones(n + 1, dtype=int)
    liouville[2:] = (-1)**omega_values[2:]
    
    cumulative_sum = np.cumsum(liouville[1:])
    
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as file:
        for i in range(n):
            file.write(f"{cumulative_sum[i]}\n")
            if (i + 1) % 100000 == 0:
                print(f"{i + 1} written")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The problem is that although this calculates the first 100 million values in under 3 minutes, the txt file is 700 MB. I don't have the disk space for 1 billion, nor the memory.
So the question is if someone has a better idea (like maybe saving only every 100th value?) or could help optimize this code in the aspects of speed, memory and disk space.
